# C++ Punctuation in Pig Latin Program

Tags: c++, punctuation

So I am trying to make a Pig Latin translator and so far my program works, but there is only one problem. I can't deal with punctuation, because when the input is an entire sentence like:

> I already hate that "language"!
>   Otput: Iway alreadyway atehay atthay "anguagelay"!

What my program does is ignoring the punctuation, so it doesn't appear in the output. This is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool IsVowel(char letter)
{
switch(letter)
{
    case 'A':
    case 'E':
    case 'I':
    case 'O':
    case 'U':
    case 'Y':
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
    case 'y':
        return true;

    default:
        return false;
}
}



void PigLatin(char *word)
{
string s1(word);
string s2;

if(IsVowel(word[0]) == true) s2 = s1 + "way";
else s2 = s1.substr(1) + s1[0] + "ay";

cout << s2 << " ";
}

int main()
{
char sentence[10000];
char *words;

cin.getline(sentence, 10000);
words = strtok(sentence, " ,.!:;""?");

while (words != NULL)
{
    PigLatin(words);
    words = strtok(NULL, " ,.!:;""?");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to ask a specific question; this is far too broad as is. A question like "how do I do it?" would also be broad. Please try a solution, then ask a specific question when you run into trouble.

Comment: Why are using both std::strings and arrays of char? And never use strtok.

Comment: Because I am new to c++ and just learning what to use and what not to. I just try using different things, in order to find something that works.

Comment: You can reduce your `cases` by half if you use `std::tolower` or `std::toupper` before the `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

`strtok` throws out the delimiters, and since you've specified all kinds of punctuation as a delimiter, the behavior you're seeing is expected.

If you want to keep the punctuation, use `strtok(sentence, " ")` instead, and then add logic to `PigLatin` that will treat non-alphabet characters differently. The best way I can think of for doing this is to write a for-loop over the characters in the string, writing them out one by one, with special logic to handle the first and last alphabet characters.